# MsMpEng makes computer unusable

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender, high-cpu-usage

Every day for the first 8 hours or so, my computer is unusable due to `MsMpEng.exe` taking 100% CPU while scanning my file systems for viruses (I think). I've already excluded a whole bunch of folders. Weird thing is that when I go to `Settings` and look at `Virus and Threat protection`, under `Current Threats`, it says `Last Scan: today, 04:30, lasted 2h41m`. Yet, here I am at 11:45 and `MsMpEng` is still pegging all four cores. `ProcMon` indicates that it is reading the filesystem a lot....

[image: Process Explorer screenshot]

One site I looked at suggested setting `Affinity` for `MsMpEng`, but I get `Access Denied`, even from an elevated `Process Explorer`.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: So when you use _ProcMon_, do you know the files it scans? Do you think they belong on your PC? Have you identified any particular thing you do that triggers the scan? // Also, do you have a SSD or an HDD?

Answer (score 1):

> Every day for the first 8 hours or so, my computer is unusable due to
> MsMpEng.exe taking 100% CPU

If you cannot use your computer for 8 hours, something is very wrong.

(1) Go into Windows Defender settings, Viruses and Threats, and set for an OFFLINE scan. Restart and let it scan and see if it finds viruses. It will isolate them if it finds viruses.

(2) If not, something has gone very wrong with Windows Defender. Back up your documents and reinstall Windows fresh.  I am fairly sure a simple Repair will not fix what you have.  Profile Error or very serious damage requires a reinstall and recovery